# Problemas com rota angular 2 e laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, angular, angular-routes

Tenho um sistema em laravel 5.3, e estou colocando o angular 2 para cuidar do front-end.
Tenho vários módulos, ex: empresas.
A rota /empresas irá levar para a listagem de empresas ficando assim:
localhost:8000/empresas ...
Mas tem o porém, nessa view, eu carrego o app.component do angular2 para fazer um roteamento ( para fazer uma single page de empresas ), mas quando carrega o route do angular 2, ele some o link no angular ficando somente localhost:8000, e dá alguns erros, tipo:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes:
>   'empresas'

Mas mesmo aparecendo esse erro, tudo funciona, mas o problema é que some o Url do laravel e fica praticamente no root do angular...
Pensei em algo do tipo: que tenho que carregar o angular ja com o /empresas ( como root ), mas como fazer?

Comment: Pode postar códigos para exemplificar a pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui, para quem tiver dúvida.
fiz 2 passos:
-> no index.php eu coloquei

```
 <base href="/empresas">
```

pois antes estava somente

```
<base href="/">
```

por isso ele voltava o endereço pra localhost:8000.
E referente ao erro, faltou especificar a rota root, que no caso fica vazio "".
Obrigado pela atenção